# Changing texture on gameobject in Unity using c# script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, windows-phone

I have created a dressup game in Unity using c# script which changes the texture on the body when I click the change button using the following code:

```
gotexture = GameObject.Find ("Body");
Texture2D mytexture=(Texture2D) Resources.LoadAssetAtPath("Assets/characters/Female/textures/texture2.tga",typeof(Texture2D));
gotexture.renderer.material.mainTexture = mytexture;
```

This code changes the texture on the body when I run the project in unity but when I build the project for Windows Phone and run it, the texture doesn't change when button is clicked.
are there any settings of the textures to be changed when using it on Windows Phone? The textures are tga files.

Answer (score 0):

When you build the project, your resources are not living in the same file paths as they are in the project. Instead of using `Resources.LoadAssetAtPath`, just use `Resources.Load`.

In order to use this though, you need to put anything that you might dynamically load like that under a folder called Resources. For example,

```
Resources
|___
    -Textures
    -Sound Effects
    -Prefabs
    -etc
```

Now you can load those assets like so:

```
Resources.Load("Textures/myTexture");
```

This is really handy for loading prefabs too! And it should work no matter where you run it.

**Note**: I believe you omit the file extension when using it like this. I don't quite remember and I'm not in a place where I can test it. If it doesn't work, just play around with the filename until it works.