# How to change texture on multiple objects on a button click?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Would be grateful for the advice.

- I'm working on a simple 3D scene in Unity.
- I have a canvas with a Scroll View full of buttons.
- I have several 3D planes hanging in the air.
- When the user clicks on a button, textures on the planes should change. So for example, if I click on a button "fruits", I should see different images of fruits on the planes, if I click "vegetables" - different images if vegetables, etc.

What would be the best way to implement it?
I can create a script with a bunch of public texture variables, drag all the images there, and then hardcode which texture goes to which plane on which button click. But is there a better (but not too complex) solution?

Comment: similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22194616/changing-texture-on-gameobject-in-unity-using-c-sharp-script?rq=1). maybe it helps

Comment: @BarışCanYılmaz Thank you, interesting but not exactly what I need. This way I'll have to include a path to every texture. I would rather add them to public variables in the script. I wondered if there is a better solution that would include less hardcoding, but maybe this question is too general.

Answer (score 0):

im guessing what you are trying to do is,  **when a certain button is pressed, it will run a script that changes one of the planes to a certain material**

here is some example code to give you an example.

```
public Material[] textures;
public GameObject[] planes;

public void ChangeTexturetosomefruit()
{
    planes[0].GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = textures[0];
}

public void ChangeTexturetosomeotherfruit()
{
    planes[1].GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = textures[1];
}
```

and inside the editor, you can then drag in the materials in the corresponding index.

[the Array List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPrXB.png)

NOTE: you should remember which texture and which plane you put on which index.
and this should become pretty simple to do.

the reason i started with index 0 is because thats the first index and i was setting the *first* **gameobject's** *material* to the *first* **material** in the **textures** Array